# NumPy on Python 3.3 on Windows 8

Tags: python, numpy, windows-8

I am trying to get NumPy to work on my new Windows 8 installation, with Python 3.3 installed. When I try (both) installers from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), they crash when I click 'Install'.

Has anyone had success with the same setup?

---

EDIT: Error image: [image]

Comment: You don't say what kind of crash it is.  A common issue is trying to install a 32-bit module on a 64-bit Python.  Check that one out?

Comment: `Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32.` I downloaded 32 bit installers.

Comment: OK, not that then.  Whhat kind of crash was it?

Comment: I added an image, that's all the info I have.

Comment: Sorry, I can't read Dutch (please forgive me if I'm wrong with the language).  Even if I could I suspect that these are just Microsoft weasel words to the effect "it went wrong".

Comment: Exactly, that's why I didnt take the time to translate it. I have no idea where to find error reporting in Windows 8, that's why I am asking on SO.

Comment: This looks like a tricky one. I tried installing numpy using `pip install numpy` but it's missing Atlas, Blas and Lapack. Some Google-fu suggests that it isn't very straightforward to install those on Windows, but you could give it a try.

Comment: It worked fine for me when combined with Python 2.7. Try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, from the capture, that your trying to instal version:

*numpy-unoptimized-1.6.2.win32-**py3.3**.‌exe*

However, I just checked the [site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) this morning, and the latest available version is:

*numpy-unoptimized-1.6.2.win32-**py3.2**.‌exe*

Have you tried the installer again lately (using the latest build)?